# Bulk delete Facebook conversations

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know if there's any software of any kind (app, script, program...) of any platform that allows mass deletion of Facebook **conversations**?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. Facebook applications can only delete content they own/posted. In addition Facebook doesn't deal in the negatives, so applications like these are swiftly banned/deleted.

Even if you got a script to automatically click delete in a browser simulated window, your account would be disabled faster than the script would finish.

Comment: So you are saying, that if I start to mass delete all my conversations one by one clicking my mouse with my own finger without stopping before I finish, my account could get disabled?

Comment: @Karolinger "Even if you got a script to automatically", if you made script as slow as you click then I'm not really sure. The point is there are blocks in place to block mass deletion of items